# Export Excel Function as a SQL request result

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, function, export

I am facing a weird behavior while exporting an output coming from oracle SQL. I am launching the below query:

```
select '=sum(1,2)' from dual
```

Then I right click on the output data and I export it to excel.

I am getting the following result in excel:

The function is presented as a string (the result in the cell is not "3", but rather "=sum(1,2)".

In order to fix this I had to click on the function then click on the Enter button on the keyboard. 
[excel file picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DbZL.jpg)

Is there a way to force excel to directly understand that the string is a function ?

Comment: use SELECT  ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2) FROM dual as a query.

Comment: The aim of this case is to be able to export a function to excel and let excel recognize it as an excel function

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuing you are on SQL Developer here)

There might be other ways, but a little trick I've used in the past is rather tahn Right Click => Export, simply do:  Select-All, Copy.  Then just Paste into Excel and that seems to preserve the formula definition.

A little animated GIF showing that here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCKQJ.jpg

Comment: Correct, I am using SQL Developer. The solution you proposed will solve the issue. But using export is a must on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following Macro will fix it. Its a work around to this behavior

for each c in activesheet.usedrange.columns("AD").cells: c.formula=c.formula: next